# how to restrict TcpClient to wait for a connection or client for specific time than stop for accepting clients?

Tags: c#, winforms, client

I am using a simple client interaction in which i use

```
TcpClient c = t.AcceptTcpClient();
```

now it waits indefinately for a client to register.Now what i want is it wait for say 5 mins and then automatically stop to listen

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a Windows Service, you could use a Timer:

```
System.Timers.Timer myTimer;
```

In your service's OnStart event:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    MyListener.StartListening();
    myTimer.Start();
}
```

In the Timer's Elapsed event:

```
private void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MyListener.StopListening();
    myTimer.Stop();
}
```

This might fullfill your immediate needs, but I'd also suggest having a look at [Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(VS.71).aspx).

***Edit**: The same principle applies using a Timer with Winforms.

Comment: Note that the call to AcceptTcpClient will throw a SocketException if you call Stop on the Listener while AcceptTcpClient is still blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `Pending` method of the `TcpListener`.
Something like

```
private TcpClient TryToConnect() {    
    DateTime dtStart=DateTime.Now;    
    while(CheckTime(dtStart)) {    
      if(t.Pending()) { return(t.AcceptTcpClient());  } //someone wants to connect

      //maybe it's a good idea to give some resources to other processes    
      Thread.Sleep(100);    
    }    
    //no one came in here    
    return(null);
}
```

`CheckTime(DateTime p)` - is a method (you have to write) which checks `DateTime.Now` against the parameter. If there is time left return `true` - else return `false`.